# Redirect Authorization failure in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, authentication

I have been doing this research for 2 days now, but i cant seem to find the answer.

How to redirect user to a specific page
This is what I have now:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Member/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

What i want to do is if user isn't authenticated redirect to this url: ~/Account/Member/LogOn"
but if the user is already authenticated but not authorized, I want to redirect to this url:
~/Account/Member/Unauthorized"

Is there anyway to do this without creating a custom authentication attribute?'

Thanks

Comment: Is this for a specific controller or all?

Comment: Controller that I use [Authorize(role="admin")] on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a base controller class and override OnActionExecuting method and then inherit that controller. See following reference for details.

[How to redirect from OnActionExecuting in Base Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller)

Answer (score 1):

The above code works with the `[Authorize]` attribute so that if the user doens't match the Authorize criteria or not authenticiated then they are bounced to the `loginUrl` Url.

For example,

`[Authorize]` just checks that they are authenticated.

`[Authorize(User="User1")]` and `[Authorize(Roles="Manager")]` both require authentication and to match the authorization criteria specified.

However, I don't think you can redirect differently for each.