# MVC5 [Authorize] redirecting to default route instead of attribute route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following:

```
    [Route("whitelist")]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
    public ActionResult Whitelist() {
        var vm = new WhitelistViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }

    [Route("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

However, when I navigate to `/whitelist` as an unauthenticated user, I get navigated to /Account/Login, which is invalid.  How do I tell MVC5 to use the attribute routes when redirecting in this case?

Comment: Why is it invalid? You have `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` on the `Whitelist()` method so if you not authorized you would be redirected to `Login()`. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it's invalid because the route to Login is "login", as overridden via attribute routing.

Comment: Please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080872/redirect-authorization-failure-in-mvc Override OnActionExecuting. We can do a lot things in this action similar to we do something in page preload before page_load.

Comment: @user666, Sorry, don't understand what your saying. Do you have multiple methods named `Login()` and this one is not in the `AccountController`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - the route /Account/Login is not valid because I have overridden it!!!

Comment: @HarrisYer - I have just laid down the override code but don't know how to determine if the request is being rejected due to auth issues - how can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean you have _overidden it_? The login page is defined in `web.config` - `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" /></authentication>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I'm saying it's overridden because I've overridden it via the attribute route.  The default route no longer works (as intended)

Comment: @StephenMuecke your method of updating the web.config does not work either.  When I get redirected to log in, it's to "Account/Login", when it should be "login", despite specifying "login" in web.config

Comment: I sorry I no have environment to test, but in the OnActionExecuting, we should able to get some login information from the default login object by MVC, just like we know login name everywhere.

Comment: The method is named `Login` and your `[Route]` is also "Login". What is it you think your overriding? (and I haven't shown you a method of _updating the web.config_, just the default value in web.config, which is saying _if the user is not authorized, redirect to /Account/Login_)

Comment: @StephenMuecke - if I override with attribute "login", the path is "/login", **NOT** "/Account/Login".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`, you'll need to change your default login path for redirects.

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/login")
```

The reason is since you have added an attribute route, then the existing route is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I copy from some website, I using notepad to combine, but ideally is here.

```
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        IPrincipal user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;  
        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Redirect to login page
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "Login" }, 
                    { "action", "NoAccess" } 
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using this, specifying the role via `Authorize(Roles = "Admin")` no longer works (Roles is not recognized).

Comment: Hi SB2005 you mean Roles = "Admin" will give error?

Comment: Yeah, it stays red / error in VS if I use the overridden attribute :/

Comment: We didn't override the attribute, we only create OnActionExecuting in base controller and inherit by all controllers, so they know what to do before page load. Just like I control the UICulture here for multilingual.