# Redirecting from OnActionExecuting -- Matched route does not include a 'controller' value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

This should be a super easy task - redirecting from a base controller. Here's an exemplary reference, but does not cover the error I'm experiencing: [Redirecting from OnActionExecuting in a Base Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller)

#### Code:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (myObject == null) {
        // System.InvalidOperationException: The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required.            
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {{ "controller", "controllerName"}, {"action", "actionName"}});

        // Throws the same exception: 
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("actionName", "controllerName");
    }
}
```

#### Rendered URL:

```
http://localhost/controllerName/actionName?controller=controllerName&action=actionName
```

When debugging, the redirect object passed to the Result property contains both a controller and action value. And in the returned URL it is also present.

#### Question:

Why is it complaining that there is no controller value? And why does it show the controller and action values in the query string in addition to the normal format?

#### Updated:

```
// hard coded URL produces the same result. What am I misunderstanding?
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Employee/Create");
```

Comment: sadly, this was a programmer error. please vote to close.