# ASP.NET MVC4: How to redirect to setup-like page after fresh installation of web app?

Tags: c#, redirect, asp.net-mvc-4, installation

I'm building a quite complex web application for data visualization and messaging that is going to be installed on many servers. The SQL database it depends on gets partially filled by another application that runs on the server, but some tables which are needed by the web application itself are not generated automatically, so I build a check-up into the constructor of my EF DbContext. It verifies that the needed tables exist in the database and creates them in case they are not present.

That works quite well. Now I want to check these tables for the existence of some entries that are needed for correct operation. If these values do not exist, I want the user (any user) to be redirected to some kind of setup page, where the fundamental settings of the web app can be configured. You can think of it to be quite similar to these typical installation procedures you get when you browse to a freshly installed TYPO3 or Wordpress on a webserver, where you can set the basic settings.

Now I was wondering what would be the best practice to do it: should I create a "flag", some static bool in global.asax.cs (maybe something like ***needsSetup***), that I check in the default controller and then conditionally redirect to the setup view? Or can/should this be done with some kind of filter? Or are there better ways to do it?

Thanks in advance for your help on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a base controller and override OnActionExecuting method, where you will check if system is ready, if not redirect to your setup action here is similar post [How to redirect from OnActionExecuting in Base Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller). Inherit all controllers (except Setup one) from that base class and you will get what you want

Comment: Thanks Alexandr, that sound quite promising. In fact, it seems to be quite similar to using a filter, but on a lower level. Putting a filter attribute on each controller or deriving each controller from a customized base controller - it's probably the same effort, as you have to touch at least each controller. I believe it works well, no question about that, but I think I'll keep the question open for while for some more alternate thoughts about this topic.

Comment: In my opinion inheriting from a base class is a "cleaner" way to do it, and it is likely you might use the base controller for other things like exception handling and etc