# Is it possible to change the action name before it's invoked?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know that you can use `OnActionExecuting` or an Action filter to inject parameters to an action method, but is it possible to change the action name itself?  I was tempted to try this:

```
    Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(filterContext As ActionExecutingContext)
        filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName = "SomethingElse"
    End Sub
```

But this won't compile, because `ActionName` is ReadOnly.  Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can change what action gets invoked by doing a redirect from within your OnActionExecuting by doing something like this:

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary() {{"action", "Index"}, {"controller", "Home"}})
```

Also take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller).