# How can I make an action filter cause a filtered action to return HttpNotFoundResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http, httpresponse, action-filter

I have a custom action filter for very explicit content length limiting. It does its work like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength >= MaxLength)
    {
        throw new HttpException("MaxLengthFilter: Request has Content-Length > " + MaxLength);
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

I would prefer if any action invoked for a content length exceeding the maximum returned a more meaningful result, such as HTTP 404.13. If I were filtering directly inside the action, I could use '  return new HttpNotFoundResult()', but the filter's `OnActionExecuting` method is type `void`.

This is further complicated in that some actions that need filtering are `ActionResult` while some are `JsonResult`, and the latter needs serialization of the `HttpNotFoundResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it isn't necessary to throw exception. You could redirect to custom error action. 
Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller) like this.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentLength >= MaxLength)
    {
       filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Error401_13", "Error"); //for example
       return;
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Where `Error401_13` would do a simple `return new HttpNotFoundResult`, I presume? Indeed a step in the right direction. I somehow never figured I could just return a redirect in the filter.

Comment: On second thoughts maybe a `Server.Transfer` is better than a redirect. This is a murky ajax world and I'd like to avoid browser round trips.

Comment: Error401_13 can return result at your purposes. if you need error page, then return action, if you need return error code, then throw exception, if you need some json responce then return `Json(new {yourResponce});`