# Redirect in custom action filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating custom filter in asp.net `MVC 5` and I am trying to redirect to a specific controller in the method `On Action Executing`  I have tried `Redirect To Action` and its not work any suggestion?
i am using this filter in web api controller
here is my code :

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    Uri MyUrl = actionContext.Request.RequestUri;
    var host = MyUrl.Host;

    if (host == "localhost")
    {
       // redirect should be here
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: `its not work` what does this mean? You need to share the code and also tell us where do you use the custom filter. Did you debug the code? Are you able to debug the Custom filter code ?

Comment: i update my question and i add the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect from OnActionExecuting in Base Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller)

Comment: What version of MVC you are using?

Comment: @SeM if you notice my code don't have filterContext. its actionContext so actionContext don't have .result so that code in that question it will not work

Comment: @PSK i am using version 5.2.3

Comment: guys its web api application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For WebApi you can use [HttpActionContext.Response Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpactioncontext.response(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://www.example.com");
    actionContext.Response = response;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `MVC 5.2.3`, you action filter should look like following.

```
 public class CustomActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {

        }
    }
```

For redirection to a action, you can use code like following.

```
 filterContext.Result =
            new RedirectToRouteResult(
                   new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            { "controller", "ControllerName" },
                            { "action", "Action" }
                        });
```