# Redirecting to action from OnActionExecuting not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have tried many options like below with taking answers from many SO questions

```
filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }));
                        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }));
                        filterContext.Result.ExecuteResult(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext);


filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Index", controller = "Home" }));
                        return;

filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/");
```

But none of the options redirect, it calls index method of home controller but redirection is not working.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect from OnActionExecuting in Base Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214774/how-to-redirect-from-onactionexecuting-in-base-controller)

Comment: @SᴇM, Yes, but answers is not working, I included answer in my post

Comment: I don't see any attempt to use `RedirectResult` as answered in duplicate question.

Comment: I believe RedirectToRouteResult is same, I tried that also, let me include this also in post

Comment: What's happening after redirect call?

Comment: It does not redirect the page. however it hits the action when I put the debugger

Comment: Can you post your action too?

Comment: action is just a p.lane view, nothing inside, a login page only

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!Request.Browser.Cookies)
                ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Please enable cookie in your browser";

            return View();
        }